# Существует назначенный этой команде Command открытый DataReader, который требуется предварительно закрыть

Tags: c#

```
num = textBox5.Text;
using (OleDbConnection oledb = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\WhiteChemist-PC\source\repos\ГСМ\ГСМ\GSM.accdb"))
{
    oledb.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(string.Format($"SELECT (Normaras) FROM [Table] WHERE [Numb] = '{0}'", num), oledb);

    using (OleDbDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        norma = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true && comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            try
            {
                k = int.Parse(norma);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            nadb = (k* (5 / 100));
            command = new OleDbCommand(string.Format($"INSERT INTO [Table].[(Nad)] VALUES ('{0}')", nadb.ToString()), oledb);
            while (dataReader.Read() == true)
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

В строке `norma=command.ExecuteScalar().ToString()` выбивает исключение:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Существует назначенный этой команде Command открытый DataReader, который требуется предварительно закрыть."

До этого никогда при работе с бд не возникало таких ошибок.Кто знает в чем дело?

Comment: У одной команды вызывается и `ExecuteScalar`, и `ExecuteReader`. Оставьте что-то одно.

Comment: Ох, до конца код не досмотрел. У вас там еще и переопределяется команда. Код удалить, автора сжечь (можно наоборот), после чего написать с нуля. Используя `using` для всех `Disposable` объектов (в том числе command).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не стоит предлагать жечь и удалять кого-то только потому, что он немного ошибся в коде.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я прекрасно понимаю что я пишу много говно кода. Но ты понимаеш если я придумаю какой нибудь красивый костыль который будет работать как надо то в моей шараге все равно никто не оценит. Поэтому я и не заморачиваюсь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в коде вызывается ExecuteReader,  результат которого потом не используется (т.к. реальное значение вы строчкой ниже пытаетесь получить через ExecuteScalar, вызванный у той же команды).

Если подразумевается обработка только одной строки - удалите ExecuteReader и завязанный на него цикл.

Если подразумевается обработка нескольких строк - вычитывайте значение norma из reader, внутри цикла - а не вызовом ExecuteScalar.

Comment: я убрал using и сделал строку получения значений такой:
 norma = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection).ToString();
но в дебагере показывает значение "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader".

Comment: @GnomSkull Ну так и должно быть - вы получили reader,  теперь вычитывайте из него значения по одному, через ReadInt32 - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader